# Generic date and time parsing in java 8

Tags: java, datetime

I was recently trying to make a generic date and time parsing method with the java 8 time API, mainly for interfacing with older code using `Date`.

I wanted to do something like that:

```
public static Date parse(String dateStr, String pattern) {
    return Date.from(Instant.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)));
}
```

The problem is that with the time API, the class to use depends on the pattern `DateTimeFormatter.parse` will never fail but will return a `TemporalAccessor` which is horrible to work with and convert to a usable class.

And `LocalDateTime.parse` will fail if the pattern has no time information like "dd/MM/yyyy". Other classes like `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, etc. will all fail to parse if the pattern doesn't match the expected class.

Ideally, I'd like a way to parse leniently and return an Instant, with default values for missing fields, but I can't find a way to do that.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you looking for [`parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-)?

Comment: What are some of the "default values for missing fields" that you have in mind? I feel this isn't intuitive to set at all, when you allow literally any format at all.

Comment: In what context do you need this? For my part I would be unhappy about knowing next to nothing about the data that I am to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder::parseDefaulting` to set default values.

```java
var now = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern(pattern)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, now.getOffset().getTotalSeconds())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, now.getYear())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, now.getMonthValue())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, now.getDayOfMonth())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, now.getHour())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, now.getMinute())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, now.getSecond())
    .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
Instant dt = Instant.from(formatter.parse(str));
```

Note that it's important to first append the pattern using `appendPattern`, and then set all your defaults using `parseDefaulting`.

Also note that I used the current time stamp to fill the defaults. So, for example, if you left out the year, it takes the current year (2022 at the time of writing). Of course, the defaults depend on your exact use case.

Examples:

At the time of writing, it's *2022-06-09T17:18:36+02:00*.

```java
System.out.println(parse("9-6", "d-M"));
System.out.println(parse("2023", "uuuu"));
System.out.println(parse("10:13", "H:m"));
System.out.println(parse("25 Dec, 16:22", "d MMM, H:mm"));
```

resolves to

```
2022-06-09T15:18:36Z
2023-06-09T15:18:36Z
2022-06-09T08:13:36Z
2022-12-25T14:22:36Z
```

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I missed it while checking the API. Thanks